equivalence of line bundles and divisors without invertible sheafs
Let $M$ a smooth projective variety. It is well-known that there is an equivalence between
the divisor class group $Cl(M)$ (divisors modulo linear equivalence) and the Picard group $Pic(M)$ (line bundles modulo isomorphism).
This result is known to be false for smooth complex (non-algebraic) manifolds, for instance Inoue surfaces.
I would like to understand why the proof for algebraic varieties do not work for complex manifolds.
I guess part of my problem is that I do not quite grasp the subtleties of the proof in the algebraic case. The usual proofs use the language of invertible sheaves and I get lost in the process.
Here is my attempt at a direct proof without introducing invertible sheaves. We have the natural map
$$
\Phi: Cl(M) \to Pic(M)$$
which sends a Cartier divisor $(f_\alpha)_\alpha$ to the line bundle with transision functions $g_{\alpha \beta}=\frac{f_{\beta}}{f_{\alpha}}$. The map $\Phi$ is always injective (even if $M$ is non-algebraic holomorphic). We need to prove surjectivity.
Take a line bundle $L \to M$, and two trivialiazing open sets with triavizations $\varphi_\alpha: L|_{U_\alpha} \to U_\alpha \times \mathbb{C}$, $\varphi_\beta: L|_{U_\beta} \to U_\beta \times \mathbb{C}$. Take the local non-vanishing sections $s_\alpha(z)=\varphi_\alpha^{-1}(z,1)$, $s_\beta(z)=\varphi_\beta^{-1}(z,1)$.
In the intersection $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$ we have $s_{\beta}=g_{\alpha \beta} s_{\alpha}$.
Now, if $M \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is projective algebraic, then $L$ can be given an algebraic structure by GAGA, so we can take trivializing sets which are Zariski-open of the form $U_{\alpha}=\{h_\alpha \ne 0\}$, $U_{\beta}=\{h_\beta \ne 0\}$. The transition function $g_{\alpha \beta}$ are in the algebraic structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}(U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta})$, hence they are given by the restriction of a rational function of $\mathbb{P^n}$ to $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$, so $g_{\alpha \beta}=\frac{g}{h_\alpha h_\beta}$ for some polynomial $g$. From the equality $s_{\beta}=g_{\alpha \beta} s_{\alpha}$ we get $s_\beta h_\beta=\frac{g}{h_\alpha} s_{\alpha}$, so this section may be globally defined in $M$, giving a rational section whose divisor recover the line bundle $L$.
Is the above proof more or less correct? If so, the main point where we need $M$ to be algebraic is the existence of trivializing sets which are Zariski-open, would you agree?
Thanks in advance for any correction, comment, clarification, etc.

I think the answer is yes I guess I have two problems in the holomorphic case: the trivializing sets aren't Zariski open, and also locally defined functions aren't rational so I can't use the zeros or poles.

Ok, for complex manifolds one could try to replace rational functions by meromorphic ones, so we arrive at the same issue: while in projective varieties there are many rational functions, in complex geometry there may not be meromorphic functions...
